# Error copying folder using COPY --from from another layer

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

The Dockerfile uses the COPY --from command from the other build Node layer, but the generated directory is not found.
Note 1: This Dockerfile works locally on my machine doing builds normally.
Note 2: In the execution log it mentions the removal of an intermediate container, is that it?  Would it be possible to preserve this container so that the copy works?

```bash
FROM node:16.16 as build
# USER node
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install --location=global npm@latest && npm install --silent
COPY . .
ARG SCRIPT
ENV SCRIPT=$SCRIPT
ARG API_URL
ENV API_URL=$API_URL
ARG API_SERVER
ENV API_SERVER=$API_SERVER
CMD ["/bin/sh",  "-c",  "envsubst < src/proxy.conf.template.js > src/proxy.conf.js"]
RUN npm run ${SCRIPT}

FROM nginx:1.23
VOLUME /var/cache/nginx
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=build /app/dist/siai-spa /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./config/nginx-template.conf /etc/nginx/nginx-template.conf
```

```
b9ed43dcc388: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:db345982a2f2a4257c6f699a499feb1d79451a1305e8022f16456ddc3ad6b94c
Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:1.23
 ---> 41b0e86104ba
Step 15/24 : VOLUME /var/cache/nginx
 ---> Running in dc0e24ae6e51
Removing intermediate container dc0e24ae6e51
 ---> 3b2799dad197
Step 16/24 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Running in f30edd617285
Removing intermediate container f30edd617285
 ---> 21985745ce49
Step 17/24 : COPY --from=build /app/dist/siai-spa /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY failed: stat app/dist/siai-spa: file does not exist
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How does siai-spa get created?

Comment: "ng new siai-spa". It's a Angular 14 app.

Comment: Did you try some basic debugging steps like running `RUN ls /app` or `RUN ls /app/dist`? The error is telling you the path doesn't exist. Have you confirmed whether that's correct or not?

Comment: Yes! RUN ls /app, folder does not exists!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem!
The difference was that locally I used docker-compose which captures the build arguments from the .env file. The npm run command did not override the ${SCRIPT} variable as the docker command does not use the env file, required to pass through the --build-arg parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you should use CMD instead of RUN while `npm run ${SCRIPT}` as this needs to be executed during container running time rather than image build time.

Comment: ...it might be a good idea to put a specific command you want to run, like `npm run build` – this doesn't seem like something where it's especially useful to parameterize it.

Comment: Ok! OK! The Dockerfile looks like this now... CMD ["/bin/sh",  "-c",  "envsubst < src/proxy.conf.template.js > src/proxy.conf.js && npm run ${SCRIPT}"] - But, not success

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).